# Bigquery returns could not parse as a timestamp for a string field

Tags: google-bigquery, pentaho

I'm trying to upload a csv file output that I got from Pentaho transformation to bigquery. One of the columns which is a string type has data as OU_US. Bigquery throws an error

> Could not parse 'OU_US' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]

I'm confused because OU_US is a string type and the error says cannot parse as timestamp. I checked if the right type is shown in pentaho csv output step and it displays correctly as string.

Any advise on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to upload it to existing table ? Do you have jobid for the upload that failed ?

Comment: Is the column type of the Bigquery table timestamp?

Comment: Any Luck with this issue?